# Starting AKS job programmatically from a container running in the same cluster

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to start a job in an AKS cluster from a container running in the cluster. This is the F# code (.NET 8)

```
let startJob (yaml: string) = 
    let job = KubernetesYaml.Deserialize<V1Job>(yaml)
    let client = new Kubernetes(config)
    client.BatchV1.ReplaceNamespacedJob(job, job.Metadata.Name, job.Metadata.Namespace()) |> ignore
```

The yaml is correct because I can start it successfully from kubectl. However when I try from the code I get a Forbidden exception.

```
[01:06:24 ERR] Connection id "0HMRLS62EJ1DS", Request id "0HMRLS62EJ1DS:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. # {"EventId": {"Id": 13, "Name": "ApplicationError"}, "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel", "RequestId": "0HMRLS62EJ1DS:00000001", "RequestPath": "/train-study"}
k8s.Autorest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.IBatchV1Operations.ReplaceNamespacedJobWithHttpMessagesAsync(V1Job body, String name, String namespaceParameter, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String fieldValidation, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at k8s.BatchV1OperationsExtensions.ReplaceNamespacedJobAsync(IBatchV1Operations operations, V1Job body, String name, String namespaceParameter, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String fieldValidation, Nullable`1 pretty, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at k8s.BatchV1OperationsExtensions.ReplaceNamespacedJob(IBatchV1Operations operations, V1Job body, String name, String namespaceParameter, String dryRun, String fieldManager, String fieldValidation, Nullable`1 pretty)
at Yatp.Adapter.Kubernetes.K8s.startJob(String yaml) in /src/Adapter/Yatp.Adapter.Kubernetes/Kubernetes.fs:line 63
at Yatp.Adapter.Kubernetes.Jobs.TrainStudy.train@17.MoveNext() in /src/Yatp.Domain.Extensions/K8s/TrainStudy.fs:line 28
at lambda_method48(Closure, Object)
```

**EDIT**

I have tried creating roles and rolebinding as follows

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole|Role
metadata:
  name: yatp-role
  namespace: yatp|default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: yatp-role-binding
  namespace: yatp|default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole|Role
  name: yatp-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: yatp|default
```

where | means I have tried all combinations. Still Forbidden

Comment: I have very little knowledge about K8s, but this looks like the classic issue that the interactive user context (from `kubectl`) is different to the "runtime" security context (whatever the container is running as). Do you have visibility on the containers security context - what is it running as?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not sure what you are asking

Comment: Do you know which "user" or "claim" is being used for `kubectl`? Do you know which "user" or "claim" is being used for the docker container that throws the "Forbidden" error? Maybe work that out and wait for someone woh knows more about K8s than me. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/ https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/service-accounts/#what-are-service-accounts

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I don't know these data and neither how to determine them. Can you  give me some hints on how to get this information?

Comment: Lets wait for an expert to chime in in case I am barking up the wrong tree. In the meantime I suggest you read the links I posted and for example, check the value of `spec.serviceAccountName`. It's all part of learning more about the platform.